# Cómo copiar registros de una tabla a otra con un procedimiento almacenado, oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo la siguiente tabla JOB_HISTORY con estos registros

```
EMPLOYEE_ID START_DATE END_DATE JOB_ID     DEPARTMENT_ID

102         13/01/01   24/07/06 IT_PROG               60
101         21/09/97   27/10/01 AC_ACCOUNT           110
101         28/10/01   15/03/05 AC_MGR               110
201         17/02/04   19/12/07 MK_REP                20
114         24/03/06   31/12/07 ST_CLERK              50
122         01/01/07   31/12/07 ST_CLERK              50
200         17/09/95   17/06/01 AD_ASST               90
176         24/03/06   31/12/06 SA_REP                80
176         01/01/07   31/12/07 SA_MAN                80
200         01/07/02   31/12/06 AC_ACCOUNT            90
```

y necesito copiar los registros a otra tabla llamada "JOB_HISTORY2" mediante un procedimiento almacenado. La tabla "JOB_HISTORY2" contiene los mismos campos con la diferencia que le he agregado un nuevo campo llamado "NEW_JOB_ID" en este campo debo agregar el siguiente proceso:

```
@NEW_JOB_ID = select * from jobs where job_id like concat(
        (select lpad(job_id,2) 
         from job_history 
         where rownum=1 
         and employee_id=101), '%') and rownum=1 order by max_salary desc;
```

este procedimiento lo que me devuelve es que empleado puede postularse a un nuevo puesto de trabajo. Entonces debo añadir este proceso para cada registro que tengo en "JOB_HISTORY", pero se agregara a la nueva tabla "JOB_HISTORY2".

TABLA JOB_HISTORY2

```
COD_EMPLOYED STARTED_DATE ENDEN_DATE JOB_ID     DEPARTMENT_ID  NEW_JOB_ID
```

Comment: ¿Cual versión de Oracle usas? Y no está del todo claro de donde sale el valor para la nueva columna `NEW_JOB_ID`, porque estás haciendo `select * from jobs ...`, o sea que aparentemente devuelves varias columnas... eso me parece raro. ¿Puedes aclarar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que estás buscando es pasar datos de una tabla a otra mediante un procedimiento el siguiente ejemplo te puede servir.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MIGRAR IS 
  CURSOR c_origen IS
     SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, JOB_ID,
        DEPARTMENT_ID
     FROM JOB_HISTORY;
BEGIN
   FOR R IN c_origen LOOP
        INSERT INTO JOB_HISTORY2(EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, JOB_ID,
                                DEPARTMENT_ID)
        VALUES(R.EMPLOYEE_ID, R.START_DATE, R.END_DATE, R.JOB_ID,
                                R.DEPARTMENT_ID);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Espero te sirva el ejemplo. Dentro del LOOP podes insertar un bloque de código que te permita trabajar para obtener datos adicionales. Saludos!